# Why do I got the win32 "123" error code when I'm loging in to the postgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

**Description**

I got the win32 123 error code when I'm logining to the postgreSQL.

[win32 error code-1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3OUvs.png)

[win32 error code-2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OhDPD.png)

I find out the error code represents "The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect." so I modified the config file(C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\14\data\postgresql.conf) and result show below

[postgresql.conf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mQXfY.png)

I restart the postgreSQL service(postgresql-x64-14-PostgreSQL Server 14) but the bug still there.

Although this error occurs, I can still log in sucessfuly.

By the way I also tried to reinstall postgreSQL but the result the same.

How can I fix it?

**Environment:**

OS: windows 10 professional

Database: PostgreSQL v14(x64)

**Reference:**

1.[win32 error code] https://docs.automic.com/documentation/webhelp/english/ARA/11.2/AE/11.2/All%20Guides/Content/ucaaqc.htm